# Plotly: How to plot a regression line using plotly and plotly express?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, regression, plotly-python

I have a dataframe, df with the columns pm1 and pm25. I want to show a graph(with Plotly) of how correlated these 2 signals are. So far, I have managed to show the scatter plot, but I don't manage to draw the fit line of correlation between the signals. So far, I have tried this:

```
denominator=df.pm1**2-df.pm1.mean()*df.pm1.sum()
print('denominator',denominator)
m=(df.pm1.dot(df.pm25)-df.pm25.mean()*df.pm1.sum())/denominator
b=(df.pm25.mean()*df.pm1.dot(df.pm1)-df.pm1.mean()*df.pm1.dot(df.pm25))/denominator
y_pred=m*df.pm1+b


lineOfBestFit = go.Scattergl(
    x=df.pm1,
    y=y_pred,
    name='Line of best fit',
    line=dict(
        color='red',
    )
)

data = [dataPoints, lineOfBestFit]
figure = go.Figure(data=data)

figure.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

How can I make the lineOfBestFit to be drawn properly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Update 1:

Now that Plotly Express handles data of both [long and wide format](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/) (the latter in your case) like a breeze, the only thing you need to plot a regression line is:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', trendline="ols")
```

*Complete code snippet for wide data at the end of the question*

[image]

If you'd like the regression line to stand out, you can specify `trendline_color_override` in:

```
fig = `px.scatter([...], trendline_color_override = 'red')
```

Or include the line color after building your figure through:

```
fig.data[1].line.color = 'red'
```

[image]

You can access regression parameters like `alpha` and beta `through`:

```
model = px.get_trendline_results(fig)
alpha = model.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].params[0]
beta = model.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].params[1]
```

And you can even request a non-linear fit through:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', trendline="lowess")
```

[image]

And what about those long formats? That's where Plotly Express reveals some of its real powers. If you take the built-in dataset `px.data.gapminder` as an example, you can trigger individual lines for an array of countries by specifying `color="continent"`:

[image]

#### Complete snippet for long format

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", color="continent", trendline="lowess")
fig.show()
```

And if you'd like even more flexibility with regards to model choice and output, you can always resort to my original answer to this post below. But first, here's a complete snippet for those examples at the start of my updated answer:

#### Complete snippet for wide data

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(123)
numdays=20
X = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
Y = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y':Y})

# figure with regression
# fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', trendline="ols")
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', trendline="lowess")

# make the regression line stand out
fig.data[1].line.color = 'red'

# plotly figure layout
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title = 'X', yaxis_title = 'Y')

fig.show()
```

---

#### Original answer:

For regression analysis I like to use `statsmodels.api` or `sklearn.linear_model`. I also like to organize both the data and regression results in a pandas dataframe. Here's one way to do what you're looking for in a clean and organized way:

**Plot using sklearn or statsmodels:**

[image]

**Code using sklearn:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(123)
numdays=20

X = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
Y = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y':Y})

# regression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(np.vstack(df['X']), Y)
df['bestfit'] = reg.predict(np.vstack(df['X']))

# plotly figure setup
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='X vs Y', x=df['X'], y=df['Y'].values, mode='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='line of best fit', x=X, y=df['bestfit'], mode='lines'))

# plotly figure layout
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title = 'X', yaxis_title = 'Y')

fig.show()
```

**Code using statsmodels:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(123)
numdays=20

X = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
Y = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y':Y})

# regression
df['bestfit'] = sm.OLS(df['Y'],sm.add_constant(df['X'])).fit().fittedvalues

# plotly figure setup
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='X vs Y', x=df['X'], y=df['Y'].values, mode='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='line of best fit', x=X, y=df['bestfit'], mode='lines'))


# plotly figure layout
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title = 'X', yaxis_title = 'Y')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Plotly also comes with a native wrapper for statsmodels for plotting (non-)linear lines:

Quoting from their documentation at: https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a really intuitive and fast way of achieving, what was asked for in the question